# Entity cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: java, entity

I don't quite understand what it means when I get this message. Help is much appreciated.

```
@Override
    public int onLoop() throws InterruptedException {
        if(!myPlayer().isAnimating()){
            inventory.dropAll(Ore_id);
        }
        Entity rocks = objects.closest(Rock_id);
        if(rocks != null){
            rocks.interact("Mine Rock");
            sleep(random(25, 30));
```

I get a error message here saying `"entity cannot be resolved as a type"`  even though I have imported a library.

Comment: (1) Make sure the package `Entity` is imported again. (2) Make sure `Entity` is not package protected (default access modifier) (3) Try cleaning up the project and rebuilding

Comment: try refresh your project

Comment: how about checking the location of the jar, if it is there in the class path or not !

Comment: You do have an import statement such as `import xx.yy.Entity;` with the appropriate package name (not `xx.yy`)?